# why this code returns "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I can't work out why this code is returning a "list index out of range error. Any suggestions ?

```
img = None
data_values = ['2', '3', '4', '5']
print("before condition: ", data_values, type(data_values), len(data_values))
try:
    if any(value in data_values for value in ('20', '42')) or (img is not None):
        print("after condition")
        form_data_values[f'{question}'] = form_data
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

here is the output of that code:

```
before condition:  ['2', '3', '4', '5'] <class 'list'> 4
list index out of range
```

Comment: Get rid of the `try`/`except` and let the exception kill the program and dump a traceback that points to the line that actually raised it. This isn't a [MCVE] (we don't have a definition of `form_data_values`), and it doesn't look like an `IndexError` is possible here (if `form_data_values` was a `list`, you'd get a `TypeError` for trying to index a `list` with a `str`). Post a real [MCVE], with the actual traceback, and we can do more to help. If that's a portion of your actual code, I'm guessing you have a `try`/`except` somewhere *else* printing that error the same way.

Comment: For me it runs quietly to completion after printing the initial message, which is what I'd expect it to do.  Perhaps you have an old Python that doesn't understand `f''` strings? They are pretty new.